# Json Values from List<Map<String, Object>> in javascript emberjs

Tags: java, javascript, json, dictionary, ember.js

just wondered how to print out all values of a JSON object in emberjs or javascript. I am currently returning it from a java method.

I have returned the JSON object to my emberJs but not sure how to print out its values. Its currently printing [object, Object]...

Thanks

Comment: is the json mentioned a model?

Comment: Basically i just want to print the values of a ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> but not sure how to :/

Comment: but do you have a plain JSON object like `{...}` or is it a model like `App.Post`

Comment: its a plain one, sorry about that e.g { name : bob, age: 55, location: uk } , {name: jim, age:47, location: spain }

Comment: I guess he means a plain JSON Object. Than you could try something like this `response.forEach(function(map){for(key in map){console.log(key + ":" + map[key])})``

Comment: Sorry for the complicated code, but List<Map<String,Object>> is not a trivial data structure :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then, after the extensive comments and @mavilein's comment, here a jsbin to play with: http://jsbin.com/ucisun/4/edit

But basically as already mentioned, here an example:

```
var posts = FIXTURES.forEach(function(item) {
  for (key in item) {
    console.log(key + ", " + item[key]);
  }
});

var FIXTURES = [
  {id: 1, title: 'First post', body: 'Lorem impsum'},
  {id: 1, title: 'Second post', body: 'Dolor sit amet'},
  {id: 1, title: 'Third post', body: 'Lorem impsum foo bar'}
];
```

### Edit

To not mess around in the comments, this is how you should do it:

```
$.getJSON('/test', function(data) {
  // if data is an array of objects like [{...}, {...}] then
  data.forEach(function(item) { 
    for(key in item) { 
      console.log(key + ", " item[key]);
  });
});
```

### Edit 2

To answer your last comment, suppose you have a text area in your html markup with the id set to `myTextArea` then this is a way how you could do it:

```
var myConcatenatedText = "";
$.getJSON('/test', function(data) {
  // if data is an array of objects like [{...}, {...}] then
  data.forEach(function(item) { 
    for(key in item) { 
      myConcatenatedText += key + ", " item[key] + " - ";
      console.log(key + ", " item[key]);
  });
  $('#myTextArea').append(myConcatenatedText); 
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Would this work in the same way if the JSON object was being returned to ember via a java method?

Comment: well, this depends on the structure of the JSON object, but if it's a valid JSON then yes

Comment: so could i do this?          $.getJSON('/test', forEach(function(data){
        for(key in data) {
          console.log(key + ", " data[key]);
        })
    });

Comment: @user2654214, edited my answer to include the correction to your code example in the last comment

Comment: Thank you, sorry for all questions. Im new to ember and JSON,kind regards

Comment: How do you append each of the objects to a text area. currently its only displaying the last element of the last object.